# task scheduler manage at.exe tasks

Tags: c++, mfc, windows-xp, scheduled-tasks

When creating a new scheduled task, using CreateProcess with at.exe command, I get files in the scheduled tasks folder named at1.job, at2.job, at3.job, etc.
Now I want to delete some of them, using c++ programming. I want to search all the at files, look for a specific command in their command line, and delete those at files contain this command.
How can I do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using at.exe is too crude.  Use ITaskScheduler.  It has an Enum() and a Delete() method.  Start [reading here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381811%28VS.85%29.aspx), there's a link to an example in C++ on that page.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read it. But can I use ITaskScheduler with c++? Or is it only c#?

Comment: Read it, "there's a link to an example in C++".